# Monodevelop doesn't nothing when click on [new solution]

Tags: 18.04, monodevelop

Ubuntu 18.04
4GB ram
2.6 GHz intel core 2 duo

i tried:

- reinstall (using apt)
- change default folders
- reinstall dotnet (using    apt)

and i'm asking here 'cause there isn't apparent solution on the internet

Comment: i tried:
1) download from this website: https://www.monodevelop.com/download/      
(full autoremoved by apt)(same problem)
2) get it from updated "apt-get"
(same problem)